# Cross origin resource policy violation for JS file when setting COEP, COOP and CORP headers

Tags: security, nginx, http-headers

What is the best way to deal with the new security headers?

- Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy (COEP) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy
- Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy (COOP) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy
- Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy (CORP) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy

What I have:

```
more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: $content_security_policy";
more_set_headers 'Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy-Report-Only: require-corp; report-to="default"';
more_set_headers 'Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy-Report-Only: same-origin; report-to="default"';
more_set_headers 'Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin';
more_set_headers 'Expect-CT: max-age=86400,report-uri="https://ktkymjds.uriports.com/reports/enforce"';
more_set_headers 'NEL: {"report_to":"default","max_age":2592000,"include_subdomains":true,"failure_fraction":1.0}';
more_set_headers 'Permissions-Policy: camera=(self), fullscreen=(*), geolocation=(self), payment=()';
more_set_headers 'Report-To: {"group":"default","max_age":10886400,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://ktkymjds.uriports.com/reports"}],"include_subdomains":true}';
more_set_headers 'X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff';
# more_set_headers 'X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN';  # ImmuniWeb meckert, wenn kommentiert; PaleMoon sperrt, wenn aktiviert!
more_set_headers 'X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block';
```

- You can check with: `curl -IL https://www.geoportal.de/portal/main/`
- I have added the fourth line - without success.

The problem is I get a lot of these messages in app.uriports.com:

[image]

Should I just set COEP and COOP to `unsafe-none`? Or how can I minimise these messages?

I found out that I can add `crossorigin` to the HTML `img` tag. But what is with all the other access methods?